# Convert a n-m relationship join query to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have three tables below:

```
table patient 
{ NID *pk
  Name
  Family
 }

 table disease 
 {
   ICD_code *pk
   Title
 }

 table_patient_disease *-*
 {
  ID
  Fk_ICDcode
  FK_Patient
 }
```

it is a n-m relationship between patient and disease.
i want to write a query to select patients and their diseases
it needs to join in linq

the Sql pure query is:

```
SELECT     
  dbo.Table_Disease.*, 
  dbo.Table_PatDis.*, 
  dbo.Table_Patient.*
FROM         
  dbo.Table_Disease 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Table_PatDis ON dbo.Table_Disease.ICD_code = dbo.Table_PatDis.FK_Disease
 INNER JOIN dbo.Table_Patient ON dbo.Table_PatDis.FK_PAtient = dbo.Table_Patient.NID
```

what is the same Linq statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT     
  dbo.Table_Disease.*, 
  dbo.Table_PatDis.*, 
  dbo.Table_Patient.*
FROM         
  dbo.Table_Disease 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Table_PatDis ON dbo.Table_Disease.ICD_code = dbo.Table_PatDis.FK_Disease
 INNER JOIN dbo.Table_Patient ON dbo.Table_PatDis.FK_PAtient = dbo.Table_Patient.NID
```

Would become:

```
var results = (from d in DbContext.Table_Disease 
               join pd in DbContext.Table_PatDis on d.ICD_Code equals pd.FK_Disease
               join p in DbContext.Table_Patient on pd.FK_PAtient equals p.NID
              select new {d, pd, p});
```